# Flask behind gunicorn and supervisor - log all requests and responses

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have inherited a flask server running behind gunicorn and supervisor. In a log file I want to see:

- All incoming requests
- All outgoing responses

I have multiple gunicorn workers. My gunicorn.conf.py looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = 'gevent'

max_requests = 1000
timeout = 30
keep_alive = 2

preload = True
```

and `gunicorn.conf` for `supervisor` looks like this:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/opt/anaconda/bin/gunicorn manage:app -c /etc/config/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/root/ourthing/web
environment=PYTHONPATH=/root/ourthing/web
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/opt/logs/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/logs/gunicorn_stderr.log
loglevel=info
priority=400
```

With `loglevel=info`, I expected to see requests and responses in `gunicorn_stdout.log` and `gunicorn_stderr.log`, but no dice.

I have implemented [this](https://gist.github.com/ibeex/3257877) for logging, and it works, but to have to manually send every request and response with `logger.info` seems insane.

Is there a [setting somewhere here](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#logging) where this will just happen automagically?

If so, where do I put it?

Also, I assume all the workers write to the same log....

**EDIT:** Here is what I added to `gunicorn.conf.py` via the accepted answer:

```
accesslog = '/root/logs/accesslog.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`loglevel`](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#loglevel) configuration setting only affects the *error* log, so changing its value won't help you log successful requests and responses.

Instead, try setting [`accesslog`](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#accesslog) (to enable *access* logs) and [`access_log_format`](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#access-log-format) in your `gunicorn.conf.py` configuration file.

Comment: `accesslog` now firing away. Really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This was helpful. For anyone that is running in a container and only wants to send to stdout use `--access-logfile -`